# SQL looking for a part number ending in '~0000'

Tags: sql, search, wildcard, tilde

I am trying to find records ending in ~0000 such as ABC~0000
but everything I try doesn't seem to work.  Some examples:

```
    and left (mfr_part_number, 4) = 'ABC~'  -- finds nothing
    and left (mfr_part_number, 3) = 'ABC'   -- finds stuff
    AND RIGHT(MFR_PART_NUMBER, 4) = '0000'  -- finds nothing
    AND RIGHT(MFR_PART_NUMBER, 5) = '~0000' -- finds nothing
    and DbFunctions.Like(MFR_PART_NUMBER,'%0000') -- suggested elsewhere, but not recognized in MSSMS.
```

I am using:

```
    SQL Server Management Studio                    15.0.18206.0
    Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools        15.0.1567.0
    Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)         10.0.18362.1
    Microsoft MSXML                                 3.0 6.0 
    Microsoft .NET Framework                        4.0.30319.42000
    Operating System                                10.0.18363
```

*Thanks!*

Comment: try:  "AND RIGHT(rtrim(MFR_PART_NUMBER), 5) = '~0000.

Comment: or `AND mfr_part_number LIKE '%~0000'`

Comment: Max's solution works.  But some situations I need to use IS IN (set of 4-char strings) of up to 20 of them.  I figured that 20 LIKEs belong in FB.

Comment: The question is why the tilde isn't working like a regular ASCII if it isn't an escape character.  I tried a bunch of those too [~] etc.  Zip's answer also works but there are no trailing spaces, using LEN(mfr_part_number) and eyeballs.  400ms from 160K records is nice.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using all of those AND statements in your WHERE clause? If so, that would cause nothing to return if there's no data that matches all criteria.

Try

```
SELECT column1, column2...
FROM yourdb
WHERE MFR_PART_NUMBER LIKE '%0000'
```

Comment: I mentioned in OP that these were example failing clauses, which I expected to work.  For clarity the 20+ lines of junk were omitted.